# embedding images in multipart html email - defining the linked images correctly

Tags: python, html, html-email, multipart

I have difficulties in embedding images in a multipart email.

I am trying to send out a html file with plenty of  embedded images as mail. However, the images do not appear, and are currently just sent as attachments.

I assume I don't manage to link the html code. 
Here is part of the HTML code for the first image

```
     </v:shapetype><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_5" o:spid="_x0000_i1029" type="#_x0000_t75"
   alt="cid:image001.png@01D58F16.6A9DB2F0" style='width:441.45pt;height:183.85pt;
   visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square'>
   <v:imagedata src="somefolder-data/image001.png"
    o:title="image001.png@01D58F16"/>
```

The images are not placed in the working directory itself.

I believe the issue lies in defining the image's ID as referenced above in the HTML, which looks different from online examples. I have tried a few versions, but haven't had success.

I assumed the part following cid would be relevant (so image001.png), but it might be "image001.png@01D58F16.6A9DB2F0".

Can someone help with to create the right connection here?

```
        msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
        fp.close()

        msgImage.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='image001.png')

        # Attach part into message container.

        msg.attach(msgImage)
```

Thanks in advance